# Writing payload into android device listening for adb debug messages

Tags: android, metasploit

On **msfconsole**, if I type `info exploit/android/adb/adb_server_exec` I got on description part the following:

> Writes and spawns a native payload on an android device that is 
>     listening for adb debug messages.

What does this "listening for adb debug messages" means exactly? I don't know much about android developing but does this implies that the target device must be with "developer mode" activated or something? Please explain to me what does this phrase means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Debug mode or USB debug, [depending on OS version](http://www.androidauthority.com/about-android-debug-bridge-adb-21510/).